# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte' type to a nullable 'System.Int16' type is not valid

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have a WCF service running on IIS that calls Entity Framework for several calls.   In one call, I have 3 stored procs that must run as a unit, so I have put them in a transaction scope.  There are 4 parameters that are listed as tinyint in the stored procs, but 3 of them are converted to byte in the Function Import, while the other is converted to int32.  Everything compiles correctly, but fails when I try to run it with the following error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte' type to a
>   nullable 'System.Int16' type is not valid.

I have tried changing the byte to int16 in the Function Import, but then my code will not compile because it claims it expects a byte.

Per several comments on here, I have changed my service to a concurrency mode of single.  Any other suggestions to try?  I've been fighting this for far too many hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help to see how exactly you changed the code.

Comment: I edited the Function Import through Model Browser by selecting the appropriate parameter and changing its Type in the Properties window.

Comment: Am I just better off using an EntityCommand with this stored proc instead of using a Function Import and the DbContext?